# XAMMP MALFUNCTIONING DUE TO ADMINISTRATOR RIGHTS RESTRICTION

Tags: xampp

Goodday Comrades, please how do I enable administrator rights on my PC with respect to my XAMMP app? the Xammp is really malfunctioning due to the administrator rights restriction.

Comment: are you an administrator? if yes, you can use the Run as Administrator in the context menu. sorry for making this question as irrelevant to programming.

Comment: Noted! I have already done that- I also effected the changes in my UAC but to no avail.Really need help pls.